# Script runs fine in the terminal but is "not found" when running with ExecuteStreamCommand

Tags: apache-nifi

I am able to run a script fine when I am logged into the terminal but the same script when run inside NiFi, I am getting an error from the processor. 
I made sure that the user/group who owns the script is the same user NiFi is running as.

```
ExecuteStreamCommand[id=<id>] Failed to process session due to java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "backup.sh" (in directory "/etc/foo/bar"): error=2, No such file or directory: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "backup.sh" (in directory "/etc/foo/bar"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that **`/etc/foo/bar/backup.sh`** file available in **`all nodes of NiFi`**.